# how to create a volume from the openstack VM

Tags: openstack

I want to create a volume from the OpenStack VM. There is an option only to create a volume from snapshot and images. but I want to take a volume on the entire VM.

ANy other way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

It is a 2 step process. You need to create snapshot of the VM and then create volume from it.

If there are additional disks attached to the VM, then you can create snapshot of the volume and create new volume from the snapshot.